# Get pid by loaded module name

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, dll, pid

I need a way to get PIDs of processes that have specific 32-bit `.dll` module loaded. Powershell (x86) has `Get-Process -Module`, but it takes too long and doesn't have PID linked if `-Module` argument specified. `wmic` has fast `process`, but nothing about modules. `Psapi.h` has `EnumProcessModules`, but then I will have to get a handle for every process, which probably be quite slow. Is there any nice and fast way of doing it with cmd/powershell/standard dll?

Comment: `tasklist /m user32.dll`

Comment: Whichever means you use will be using psapi under the hood. There is generally only one way to do things on Windows. Many ways of accessing that one way.

Comment: Regular `tasklist` only searches in 64-bit modules, and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\tasklist.exe` is extremely slow (like few minutes to half an hour)